# Select interaction with openlayers: multi equals true. How to store all layers?

Tags: openlayers, javascript, layers, interaction

I have a select interaction, with `multi` option equal to `true`.
This interaction is used with popup, following code https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.popup.feature.html

I store the name of the selected layer. My question is: if the interaction has `multi` option equal to `true`, how do I store the name of all the layers that are in this space and that will be shown in the popup?

```
// Select  interaction
var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    hitTolerance: 15,
    multi: true,
    style: selectedStyle,
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,

});

    
// armazenar o layer que está com feature selecionado
let layer_selected;
select_interaction.on('select', function(e) {
    let featureSelected = e.selected[0];
    layer_selected = select_interaction.getLayer(featureSelected);  
});
map.addInteraction(select_interaction);

var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({       
    popupClass: 'default anim',
    closeBox: true,
    onclose: function(feature, layer) {
        layer_selected = null
        select_interaction.getFeatures().clear();
    },  
    select: select_interaction,
    template: function(feature, layer) {
        var tema_selected = layer_selected.get('name').substring(0, layer_selected.get('name').indexOf("_"))
                                          
        if (tema_selected === 'theme1') return template_theme1(feature);
        else if (tema_selected === 'theme2') return template_theme2(feature);
        else template_padrao(feature);


    }
});
map.addOverlay (popup);

function template_craisa(feature){
    var titulo = ''
    
    if (layer_selected.get('name').startsWith('theme1_layer1')){
        titulo = 'Theme1: Layer1'
        var template = { 
            title: 
                function() {
                    return titulo;
                },
            attributes: 
            {
                'ID': { title: '<b>Code:</b>' },
                'Nom': { title: '<b>Nome:</b>' },   
                
            }   
        };
        return template

    }
    return
}
```

[EDIT CODE]

```
const layers_selected = [];
select_interaction.on('select', function(e) {
    e.selected.forEach(function(e){
        layers_selected.push(select_interaction.getLayer(e).get('name'))
        
    });

});
```

Comment: Instead of getting just one feature and layer from `e.selected[0]` you would need to use `e.selected.forEach` or a for loop to process all the features.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I followed your help and changed the code `select_interaction.on('select', function(e) {});`
But I couldn't in the popup, to display to change each layer added in `layers_select`

Comment: The example works as expected if you click close to the intersection of three regions https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVy0O.png

Comment: @Mike, Thanks, I solved this problem with your tips and suggestions.